# Uniform Boundedness Principle

Tags: functional-analysis

This is a homework question, I have no clue where to start!

Use Uniform Boundedness Principle to prove the following statement.

A subset $X$ of a normed space $E$ is bounded if and only if $f(X)$ is bounded in $\mathbb{K}$ for each $f\in E'$ (where $\mathbb{K}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$)

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $X$ is unbounded. Hence there exists a sequence $(x_n )$ such that $||x_n ||\to\infty.$ Let us define an sequence $h_n : E' \to \mathbb{R}$ of linear functionals by $h_n (f) =f(x_n ).$ By assumptions for every $f\in E'$ the sequence $h_n (f) $ is bounded so by Uniform Boundedness Principle the sequence $||h_n ||$ is bounded but $||h_n || =||x_n ||$. Contradiction.